# How to add custom menu in Sitecore menu list

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore7

i want to add my custom application name in Sitecore Start Menu List, i'm following this article :

[Adding Application Shortcut](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/Customizing%20Sitecore%20Client/Adding%20an%20Application%20Shortcut.aspx)

it saying use Core database i'm using this, i couldn't find Layout studio, can any sitecore developer suggest me how to find this and finish my job. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think the instructions you've linked to there are out of date. I've not seen that bit of UI in recent releases of Sitecore.

Working in Sitecore 6.6 I've successfully made custom applications using these instructions:

http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/Customizing%20Sitecore%20Client/Adding%20an%20Application%20Shortcut/Creating%20an%20Application.aspx

But beware the issue that I've blogged about here. The recent revisions of Sitecore subtly break the configuration defined above, and you have to manually edit out a file extension to make everything work:

https://jermdavis.wordpress.com/2014/10/20/a-gotcha-with-custom-applications/

-- Edited to add --

Based on the "it doesn't work in 7.5" comment below, I've tried these instructions on a test instance of Sitecore 7.5 rev 141003. It seems 7.5 behaves slightly differently - but I can still make it work.

Create the item under `/sitecore/content/Applications` using the external link button for the "Application" field. With raw values displayed, it should look something like:

[image: Raw values for the application link]

And then create your application shortcut under `/sitecore/content/Documents and settings/All users/Start menu` using an internal link for the Application field. I found this still added the '.aspx' extension mentioned in my blog post, but I also found that editing it out again didn't work - it reappeared as soon as I hit save. I needed to edit out the extension from the link data using the Raw Values view in order to get the data shown below:

[image: Raw value for application shortcut]

With those things set up, refreshing the page caused the test item to appear on my start menu:

[image: Resulting start menu]

Hopefully that works for you too?

-- Further edited to add --

New blog post covering this problem in Sitecore 7.5:

https://jermdavis.wordpress.com/2015/01/19/gotchas-with-custom-apps-v2/

Comment: i'm able to create Application but when i'm adding this to shortcut menu that time it is not displayed in Menu List

Comment: Those instructions are about how to add an ASPX page (implementing your application) to the Sitecore "start menu". If that's not what you were after, I can try and help further, but I'll need some more detail about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: just i want to add a menu in Menu List, don't need to show any layout on it's click for now

Comment: it is working fine in sitecore 6.5 but not working in sitecore 7.5

Comment: Ah - right - that's probably a key bit of info. (It would be worth adding that to your question, I think) I don't have an instance of that to hand to test against right now. I'll see if I can get one together later.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Sitecore are you using? The Layout Studio is probably one of the least features in Sitecore, and personally not something I have ever used.

Instead you should create the the layout in Visual Studio - which then means your layout can be added to your Source Control System. Then follow the instructions in the link in Jeremy's answer.

If you do need to access the Layout Studio for some reason you can find it under: `Sitecore menu > Development Tools > Developer Center`. From there you can create new files/open existing files.

Comment: i create simple layout in my visual studio project and at create application time i'm giving path of this layout to application it creating fine without any error, but when i'm create shortcut menu it is not displaying in menu list

Comment: Developer Center menu is not displaying under Development Tools
http://screencast.com/t/bKKtxi5h

Comment: i'm using Sitecore 7.5, then how to i fix it in this version

Comment: Which version of Sitecore are you using? I think it may have been removed in 7.5. Adding the shortcut should be as simple as http://sitecorehelp.com/blog/6/Creating-custom-applications-in-Sitecore, make sure it is in All Users and it is not security restricted. Like I said, you don't _need_ the developer center.

Comment: following article without any mistake but it couldn't solve my issue. i'm adding, i notice one thing at Shortcut menu creation time when i insert Link that time it add .aspx extension with my Application name and when i fill it manually that time it doesn't save my value

Comment: Did you remove the .aspx extension in your shortcut definition as Jeremy's article pointed out?

Comment: when i'm removing this extension it doesn't save my values what  i'm putting

Comment: i'm giving application name as:
http://screencast.com/t/xjeYTomYK

i'm saving it but when i open it again found this blank

Comment: it is working fine in sitecore 6.5 but not working in sitecore 7.5

Comment: The recommended approach would be to use SPEAK (http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%207/SPEAK.aspx). I would raise a support ticket with Sitecore to ask why it is not working though.